# Timestamp based on cell value

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp

I've created a script that inserts a timestamp based on any update to a specific cell; however I'm trying to insert a timestamp on a specific condition: 'Complete'.

Would anyone know how to modify this script?

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();

    if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) { //checks the column 
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      //if( nextCell.getValue() !== '' ) //is empty?
      nextCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss');
    }

    if( r.getColumn() == 2 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      //if( nextCell.getValue() !== '' ) //is empty?
      nextCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss');
    }

    if( r.getColumn() == 3 ) { //checks the column - Complete
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      //if( nextCell.getValue() !== '' ) //is empty?
      nextCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss');

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome. There are several questions on this site about timestamps on Google Sheets. Did you already review them? If so, why they doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
if( nextCell.getValue() !== '' ) //is empty?
```

Should be:

```
if (nextCell.getValue() === 'Complete') {
  nextCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried myself using inspiration from this post and found to have cracked the script for the desired application.

you need to try the following:

```
 function onEdit() {
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 if( s.getName() == "Enter_Sheet_Name" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
 var r = s.getActiveCell();

 if( r.getColumn() == 7 ) { //checks the column 
        var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
  if( r.getValue() === "Complete")
    nextCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss');
  }
  }
  }
```